# ARKit – White paper sheet detection

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I would like to build a very simple AR app, which is able to detect a white sheet of A4 paper in its surrounding. I thought it would be enough to use [Apple's image recognition sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/detecting_images_in_an_ar_experience) as well as a white sample image in the ratio of a A4 sheet but the ARSession will fail.

> One or more reference images have insufficient texture: white_a4,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=One or more images lack sufficient
>   texture and contrast for accurate detection. Image detection works
>   best when an image contains multiple high-contrast regions distributed
>   across its extent.

Is there a simple way, to detect sheets of paper using ARKit? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**I think even ARKit 3.0 isn't ready for an abstract white sheet's detection at the moment**.

If you have a white sheet with some markers at its corners, or some text on it, or, even, a white sheet placed inside definite environment (it's a kind of detection based on surroundings, not on the sheet itself) – then it has some sense.

***But simple white paper has no distinct marks on it, hence ARKit has no understanding what it is, what its color is (outside a room it has cold tint, for instance, but inside a room it has warm tint), what a contrast is (contrast's important property in image detection) and how it's oriented (this mainly depends on your PoV)***.

> Suppose the common sense of image detection is that ARKit detects image, not its absence.

So, for successive detection you'll need to give ARKit not only a sheet but its surrounding as well.

[image]

Also, you can look at [Apple's recommendations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/detecting_images_in_an_ar_experience) when working with image detection technique:

> - Enter the physical size of the image in Xcode as accurately as possible. ARKit relies on this information to determine the distance of the image from the camera. Entering an incorrect physical size will result in an ARImageAnchor that’s the wrong distance from the camera.
> - When you add reference images to your asset catalog in Xcode, pay attention to the quality estimation warnings Xcode provides. Images with high contrast work best for image detection.
> - Use only images on flat surfaces for detection. If an image to be detected is on a nonplanar surface, like a label on a wine bottle, ARKit might not detect it at all, or might create an image anchor at the wrong location.
> - Consider how your image appears under different lighting conditions. If an image is printed on glossy paper or displayed on a device screen, reflections on those surfaces can interfere with detection.

**I must add that you need a unique texture pattern, not a repetitive one**.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is run a simple `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` where you periodically analyze the camera image for rectangles using the Vision framework.

This post (https://medium.com/s23nyc-tech/using-machine-learning-and-coreml-to-control-arkit-24241c894e3b) describes how to use ARKit in combination with CoreML